# Realtek ethernet port does not work in HP 1000 notebook PC with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop

A day or two back, my HP 1000 notebook had been in sleep mode for a long time. Then when I opened the screen the LAN light turned off. The weird part is that the LED for LAN glows when the screen is shut and immediately switches off as the screen opens.

After going through many forums I reached the conclusion that it's probably in 'deep sleep mode'. I removed the battery for 10-15 minutes and pressed and held the power button for 5 seconds, then after switching it off it worked fine. However the next day after going to sleep for a short period this behavior returned.

I tried doing the same things again, this time they did not work. Some forums suggested removing the RAM which I did, but it still did not work. I already changed the option of "allow the computer to shut this device to save power" in device manager when it worked. In BIOS there are no settings for power (I have updated the BIOS). It still won't work.

Could anyone help me understand if its a hardware or software issue, and are there any other steps I can take to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open Device Manager and go to Network Adapters and find the adapter.  Right-click and go to Properties and then Power Management.  Uncheck 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power'.  Also check your power profile in the control panel to see if there are settings for the ethernet there as well.